# What is the best way to run cronjob in AWS ECS?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cron, scheduled-task, amazon-ecs

I have a web app powered by Laravel that is set up on AWS ECS. I would need to run an artisan command as a cronjob.

I'm looking at "Scheduled Tasks" in ECS Cluster configuration. I can launch new tasks following the "[Scheduled Tasks (Cron)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html)" documentation on AWS. I'm using the Laravel's Task Definition in the Target which I use for web services & it has two tasks.

1. Not sure how I can invoke the artisan command
2. The scheduled task seems running forever

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault way of saying *Thanks* for the time someone took to help you :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm not familiar with Laravel or Artisan but essentially you'll need to:

1. **create a container image** with your job (*artisan*)
2. **create a task definition** that runs the *artisan* container when invoked
3. **create the cron-scheduler** to invoke the above task definition

Regarding *"The scheduled task seems to be running forever"* - **ECS Tasks** do their job and exit and are not restarted (e.g. cron jobs). **ECS Services** are restarted when they exit (e.g. web servers). Make sure you're creating a *Task* and not a *Service*. Then it should be running forever.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I found the answer from acloud.guru forum https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-ecs-scaling-docker/discussion/-LUjDTjai2ZzvemiVnk6/what_is_the_best_way_to_run_cr

Comment: Looks like AWS System Manager is the way to go...